# Assigning a variable with Dynamic data in Xquery

Tags: xslt, xquery, osb

I have a requirement where I have to validate the incoming data against data present in a constant.xml.

Say below is my constant file:

```
<Constant>
 <data>
  <Nation>India</Nation>
  <EndPointURL>customers/{$custID}/Resource</EndPointURL>
 </data>
 <data>
  <Nation>China</Nation>
  <EndPointURL>customers/{$custID}/Resource</EndPointURL>
 </data>
 <data>
  <Nation>Russia</Nation>
  <EndPointURL>customers/Resource</EndPointURL>
 </data>
</Constant>
```

and $body is as follows:

```
<body>
 <custID>1234</custID>
 <Country>India</Country>
 <ServiceURL>customers/1234/Resource</ServiceURL>
</body>
```

Here I have to check, that if $body/ServiceURL = $Constant/data/EndPointURL.

And the cardinality of data is (1...infinity).

Is their a way I can change pass original CustID fr4om Input and make a validation check with customers/{$custID}/Resource.

Presently, I am using below code to make a check.

```
let $ServiceURL :=$body/ServiceURL/text()
let $country :=$body/Country/text()
for $service  in ($Constant/data) where
        ($service/Nation/text() = $Country)
        and ($service/EndPointURL/text() = $ServiceURL) 

        return
            <ServiceURL>{fn:concat('/REALTime/',$service/EndPointURL/text())}</ServiceURL>
};
```

Please, let me know, how can I change the data of constant.xml in xquery

Answer (score 0):

The following query shows you how to expand the embedded templates in your EndPointURLs and only return the result if there is a match.

```
(: find the `data` for our `Country` :)
let $data := $Constant/data[Nation eq $body/Country]
return

(: expand the {$var} parts of the EndPointURL :)
let $parts := tokenize($data/EndPointURL, "/")
return
  let $expanded-parts :=
    for $part in $parts
    return
      if(matches($part, "\{\$[^}]+\}"))then
        let $src := replace($part, "\{\$([^}]+)\}", "$1")
        return
           $body/element()[local-name(.) eq $src]
      else
        $part
  return
    let $expanded-endpoint-url := concat("/", string-join($parts, "/"))
    return

       (: the body if the ServiceURL matches the expanded EndPointURL :)
       $body[ServiceURL eq $expanded-endpoint-url]
```

Comment: Hi Adamretter, Can you please explain the below part of the code: 


      if(matches($part, "\{\$[^}]+\}"))then
        let $src := replace($part, "\{\$([^}]+)\}", "$1")
        return
           $body/element()[local-name(.) eq $src]
      else
        $part
  return
    let $expanded-endpoint-url := concat("/", string-join($parts, "/"))
    return

       (: the body if the ServiceURL matches the expanded EndPointURL :)
       $body[ServiceURL eq $expanded-endpoint-url]

What does $1 imply here, also canb you explain me if(matches($part, "\{\$[^}]+\}")) condition.

Comment: For `replace` `$1` is the first matching group used in the regular expression, i.e. the bit between the `(` `)` in the regular expression.

Comment: the `matches` expression uses a regular expression to match any string that starts `{$` and ends `}`. I use it to decide if parts of your `EndPointURL` contains things like `{$custID}`. If I find such things I can then replace them with the real values before doing the comparison of the constants data and the body.